# Unable to write topic data to a gcs buckets from an on prem kafka topic. It keeps generating logs but doesn't write to gcs bucket

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, kerberos, google-cloud-dataproc

I am reading data from an on prem kafka topic theough a spark streaming job on dataproc cluster.

I am using kerberos for cluster authentication and basic authentication for schema registry.

I can see in the logs that I am subscribed to topic but I keep getting logs from no committed offset to resetting offset to seeking latest.

```
Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt false ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is ./fid_name.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is fid_name@domain.ca tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
principal is fid_name@domain.ca
Will use keytab
Commit Succeeded
```

```
23/06/26 20:42:37 INFO org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.AbstractLogin: Successfully logged in.
23/06/26 20:42:37 INFO org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin: [Principal=fid_name@domain.ca]: TGT refresh thread started.
23/06/26 20:42:37 INFO org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin: [Principal=fid_name@domain.ca]: TGT valid starting at: Mon Jun 26 20:42:37 UTC 2023
23/06/26 20:42:37 INFO org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin: [Principal=fid_name@domain.ca]: TGT expires: Tue Jun 27 06:42:37 UTC 2023
23/06/26 20:42:37 INFO org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin: [Principal=fid_name@domain.ca]: TGT refresh sleeping until: Tue Jun 27 04:58:31 UTC 2023
23/06/26 20:42:38 INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka version: 2.6.0
23/06/26 20:42:38 INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka commitId: 62ab7664f6e03875
23/06/26 20:42:38 INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka startTimeMs: 1687812158067
23/06/26 20:42:38 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Subscribed to topic(s): topic_1
23/06/26 20:42:38 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Cluster ID: V5F9mOvYTxSZdi3O6QF4lQ
23/06/26 20:42:38 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Discovered group coordinator broker_1:9093 (id: 2147483641 rack: null)
23/06/26 20:42:38 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] (Re-)joining group
23/06/26 20:42:38 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.MemberIdRequiredException: The group member needs to have a valid member id before actually entering a consumer group.
23/06/26 20:42:38 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] (Re-)joining group
23/06/26 20:42:41 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Finished assignment for group at generation 1: {consumer-consumger_group_name-1-f1070ddf-1ff0-4857-9664-50483f233a96=Assignment(partitions=[topic_1-0, topic_1-1, topic_1-2, topic_1-3, topic_1-4, topic_1-5])}
23/06/26 20:42:41 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Successfully joined group with generation 1
23/06/26 20:42:41 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Notifying assignor about the new Assignment(partitions=[topic_1-0, topic_1-1, topic_1-2, topic_1-3, topic_1-4, topic_1-5])
23/06/26 20:42:41 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Adding newly assigned partitions: topic_1-2, topic_1-1, topic_1-4, topic_1-3, topic_1-0, topic_1-5
23/06/26 20:42:41 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Found no committed offset for partition topic_1-2
23/06/26 20:42:41 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Found no committed offset for partition topic_1-1
23/06/26 20:42:41 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Found no committed offset for partition topic_1-4
23/06/26 20:42:41 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Found no committed offset for partition topic_1-3
23/06/26 20:42:41 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Found no committed offset for partition topic_1-0
23/06/26 20:42:41 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Found no committed offset for partition topic_1-5
23/06/26 20:42:42 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Resetting offset for partition topic_1-3 to offset 0.
23/06/26 20:42:42 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Resetting offset for partition topic_1-2 to offset 0.
23/06/26 20:42:42 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Resetting offset for partition topic_1-0 to offset 0.
23/06/26 20:42:42 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Resetting offset for partition topic_1-1 to offset 0.
23/06/26 20:42:42 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Resetting offset for partition topic_1-5 to offset 0.
23/06/26 20:42:42 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Resetting offset for partition topic_1-4 to offset 1.
23/06/26 20:42:42 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Seeking to LATEST offset of partition topic_1-2
23/06/26 20:42:42 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Seeking to LATEST offset of partition topic_1-1
23/06/26 20:42:42 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Seeking to LATEST offset of partition topic_1-4
23/06/26 20:42:42 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Seeking to LATEST offset of partition topic_1-3
23/06/26 20:42:42 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Seeking to LATEST offset of partition topic_1-0
23/06/26 20:42:42 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumger_group_name-1, groupId=consumger_group_name] Seeking to LATEST offset of partition topic_1-5
```

Dataproc command to submit the spark job below -

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --project=prj-cxbi-dev --cluster=multi-node-cluster --region=northamerica-northeast1 --class=Logr.AvroConsumer --jars=xyz_project.jar --properties="spark.submit.deployMode"="client","spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled"="true","spark.shuffle.service.enabled"="true","spark.executor.memory"="12g","spark.driver.memory"="4g","spark.executor.cores"="5","spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=kafka_np_client_jaas.conf","spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=kafka_np_client_jaas.conf","spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore.jks","spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore.jks" --files kafka_np_client_jaas.conf,truststore.jks,fid_np.keytab -- "topic_name" "schema_version" "90 seconds" "gs://checkpoint" "gs://bucket_where_data_needs_to_be_written" "job_name"
```

Comment: You've not posted any error logs or Spark code. Where are you setting `consumger_group_name`? Is that a typo? Where exactly are you trying to use GCS other than your submit command?

Comment: @OneCricketeer - I figured out why I was getting these logs and nothing was being written to the bucket. There was no messages in the topic. However I am unable to authenticate to Schema registry at the time of deserialization as soon as the records are pushed. Schema registry requires base authentication with tls certificate. Would you be able to help with that

Comment: Not really. I would point you at https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/security/index.html